# connect static database into my android app

Tags: android, sql, database, crud

guys I'm a beginner Android development, and I want to create a static database and then connected to my android application my Wishes:
user register from the application and that database should perform CRUD operation
I don't know how do I create it that database 
I need help someone help me 
Thanks

Comment: Use SQLite database

Comment: In where environment? Sorry about for the simple question :)

Comment: SQLite is a database. It can perform CRUD with your phone.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question I said in where environment I could create a SQL data base and connect in my android app

Comment: Use Google, when searching for tutorials.

Comment: Have a look on https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: i needed something like this thanks

Comment: https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create a static database and then connected to my android
>   application

The things you probably looking is [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

`SQLite` is a open source `SQL` database that stores data to a text file on a device. Android normally comes in with built in `SQLite` database implementation.

Here is one of the  [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

**P/S : If you have uninstalled the app, all the data will de gone/deleted together.**

---

Another approach is using PHP script then connects to  `MySQL` database to perform the operation. User still able to get back his/her data as long as he/she still remember username and password.

Example: [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: I want something like this if user uninstall the app all data is gone it's ok but when he reinstall the application and log in it again the user's information will be back

Comment: I think to ask my question poorly I sorry about that

Comment: You may use MySQL and PhP https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Learn about database CRUD Operation then there are Videos of Slidnered [Link for examples in Sqlite performing CRUD Operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsNgtAdlof8),
Another from the Examples of Androidhive click this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).
For getting Proper understanding with multiple tables then you can try this example from the [link for Multiple table example](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/).

I hope you will get better understanding from these examples about the CRUD operation on Sqlite database.

Comment: SQLite will delete all the data once the app is uninstalled. That's not what OP looking

Comment: when you will clear the data or uninstall it will definetely gets removed and if you want to handle it dynamically then try AmazonWebService DynamoDb or Firebase Database that will get stored.